# Google Sheets Regexextract between specific points in string

Tags: google-sheets

> ```
>       CARD TRANSACTION            12NOV21 V DEBIT              007905AED       111.04            Card Ending with 8906            Majid Al Futtaim A89517641 ATM
> ```

Hi,

I have the above bank transaction string, and I am looking to extract the description which lies between **8906** and the unique transaction code immediately beginning with **A** i.e. desired output "Majid Al Futtaim".

I tried:

> =regexextract(B2,"8906(.+)A")

But the output I get is the spaces inherent and "Majid Al Futtaim A89517641", whereas I just want "Majid Al Futtaim" only.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the sole string you've shared, this should work:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"8906\s+(.+)\s+\D*\d")`

I've made *some* predictions about variation in pattern within this formula; but there is no way to control for something the scope of which I can't see in full.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant! Merci, and thanks for helping me get a hang of regular expressions, appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. If you would, please do take a moment to mark my reply post as "Best Answer." It let's the contributor community here  see at a glance which issues have been fully resolved; and it will allow future site visitors to most quickly find relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex pattern:

```regex
Card Ending with \d+\s+([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+\b)*)
```

Your updated sheets code:

```
=regexextract(B2, "Card Ending with \d+\s+([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+\b)*)")
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NJ5sjd/1) showing that the pattern is working.

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "8906(.+)A.+"))
```

Comment: This one still gave the numbers after the A for some reason.

Comment: @WhenWordsOutPerformSilence can you share a copy of your sheet?